# Remove add to cart notification on OpenCart product pages

Tags: php, opencart

When adding a product to the cart in OpenCart a notification pops up on the top of the page. I would like to remove this notification BUT only on the product pages.

Is there a way to easily do this? I have searched up and down with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better understanding of how Opencart is structured, and some javascript basics will be very helpful for you.  Reading this would be a good place to start for the application structure:
http://docs.opencart.com/developer/module/

**Disclaimer**: I wouldn't recommend this.  how will the customer know that clicking the button worked and actually did something?

That being said, the code in question lies in: ***catalog/view/theme/{your theme}/template/product/product.tpl***

Depending on your version or theme you should look for this code (below is example of OC v1.5.6.4):

```
if (json['success']) {
    $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

    $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
}
```

And comment or remove lines like this:

```
if (json['success']) {
    //$('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

    //$('.success').fadeIn('slow');

    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

    //$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
}
```

Make sure to leave the `$('#cart-total').html(json['total']);` line as it updates the mini cart module.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying more. I already modded the store so that when a customer clicks the add to cart button they are redirected to the shopping cart page where they are given to option to continue shopping or to checkout. The reason I want to remove the notification is that when a user clicks that notification popups up in the midst of the redirect and it doesn't look very good. Also, that worked so thank you very much. I should have found this on my own but I was looking at the wrong chunk of code in the .tpl.